# How does _sopen_s manage multiple writing to same file

Tags: c++, file, crt

I have a C++ application that handles multiple connections and writes to file. When using function `_sopen_s` with parameter `_SH_DENYNO` all threads that are working simultaneously are writing in the file and I see no loss of data. Can you tell me how the access to the file is managed by the function so there is no loss of data ?

Kind regards

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft provide the source to the CRT with Visual Studio? Can't you look at that to help you get started? Or do you wonder about the native WIN32 system calls used by the CRT?

Comment: That's an OS capability, nothing to do with the CRT function.  Pretty hard to pull off correctly, getting the data interleaved into a jumble is a significant risk, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `write()`, or some OS-supplied variant of it, individual `write()` calls tend to be implemented such that each call to `write()` is atomic because of the implications of this [POSIX statement regarding `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> On a regular file or other file capable of seeking, the actual writing
>   of data shall proceed from the position in the file indicated by the
>   file offset associated with fildes. Before successful return from
>   write(), the file offset shall be incremented by the number of bytes
>   actually written. On a regular file, if this incremented file offset
>   is greater than the length of the file, the length of the file shall
>   be set to this file offset.

That's somewhat hard to implement in a way that allows for interleaved data from separate `write()` calls on the same file descriptor, because if data is interleaved the change in the file offset upon completion wouldn't be equal to the "number of bytes actually written".  So that statement could be interpreted as an implied requirement for the atomicity of `write()` calls on any "regular file or other file capable of seeking".

Also, there's the explicit [POSIX requirement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) that `write()` calls to pipes of less than or equal to `PIPE_BUF` bytes be atomic:

> *Atomic/non-atomic*: A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process.
>   This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a
>   single reader. Applications need to know how large a write request can
>   be expected to be performed atomically. This maximum is called
>   {PIPE_BUF}. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 does not say whether write
>   requests for more than {PIPE_BUF} bytes are atomic, but requires that
>   writes of {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall be atomic.

Since `write()` just gets an `int` for a file descriptor with no other information directly available as to what the file descriptor refers to, the simplest way to implement `write()` in a way that meets the POSIX requirement for atomic `write()` to a pipe is to make each `write()` call atomic.

So, while there's no *requirement* for atomicity unless you're writing less than or equal to `PIPE_BUF` bytes to an actual pipe, `write()` tends to be implemented atomically for everything.

Now, that doesn't mean that whatever the file descriptor points to won't break the data up or interleave it with other data.  For example, I wouldn't be surprised at all to see interleaved data if two threads were each to try calling one `write()` operation to stream several GB of data from MPEG files simultaneously to the same TCP socket.

And you're not actually calling `write()`.  But the underlying implementation is likely shared.

Comment: Interesting, but irrelevant as the parameter in question is Microsoft specific and `write()` on Windows is not a system call but rather built on WIN32.

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour one way or the other.  Since I would naturally queue all such operations to one thread for the writing, I never will.  No problem for me by design, no matter what the crt/OS does now, or tomorrow.  Next...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I actually do call `_write`. Thank you for the explanation.